# canActivate returning before subscribe

Tags: angular

I need to subscribe before returning a boolean to canActive. If I use `map` instead of `subscribe`, service.getCity is not called. How could I resolve this issue? `canActivate` is returning before my service returns

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let active = this.appService.isAuthenticated();

    this.service.getCity('city').subscribe(
      result => {
        if (!active) {
          this.appService.redirectUrl = state.url;
          window.location.href = result.entity;
        }else {
          this.userInteractor.setCity(result.entity);
        }
      },
      error => {console.log('erro: ' + error)}
    );

    return active;
  }
```

Comment: Can we see what you tried with `map`?

Comment: The map didn't work, my request is not called because I didn't sign up for the request

Answer (score 0):

You must include both service calls in the observables chain in such a way that you wait for both of them to emit something before continuing. One way of achieving that is by using the `forkJoin` operator.

The only catch is that you must make sure that both observables **complete** after emitting (this is important because the `forkJoin` only emits after that).

Also, notice that `canActivate` now is returning an `Observable<boolean>` instead of simply a `boolean` value.

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const active$ = of(this.appService.isAuthenticated());

    const city$ = this.service.getCity('city').pipe(
        tap(result => {
            if (!active) {
                this.appService.redirectUrl = state.url;
                window.location.href = result.entity;
            } else {
              this.userInteractor.setCity(result.entity);
            }
        },
        catchError(error => {
            console.log('erro: ' + error);
            return of(null);
        })
    );

    return forkJoin([active$, city$])
        .pipe(map(([active, _]) => active));
}
```

Another approach is chaining the result of `active$` and `city$` observables (maybe you want to grab the city just if the `active$` emits a `true` value (I hope this makes sense):

```js
...

    return active$.pipe(
        switchMap(active => {
            let c$!: any = of(null);
            if(active) {
                c$ = city$;
            } 

            return combineLatest([
                    of(active), 
                    c$,
                ]);
        })
    ).pipe(map(([active, _]) => active));
```

**[UPDATE]:** in case you're using rxjs < version 5.5.x (as per comments)

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
import { do } from 'rxjs/operator/do';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
import { catch } from 'rxjs/operator/catch';

...

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  const active$ = of(this.appService.isAuthenticated());

  const city$ = this.service.getCity('city')
      .do(result => {
          if (!active) {
              this.appService.redirectUrl = state.url;
              window.location.href = result.entity;
          } else {
            this.userInteractor.setCity(result.entity);
          }
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log('erro: ' + error);
          return of(null);
      });

  return forkJoin(active$, city$)
      // v => [active, city] || [active, null]
      .map((v: any[]) => v[0]));
}
```

*If it's up to you to decide it, consider updating `rxjs` to the latest version. As the operators are pipeable on versions >= 5.5.x, the tree-shaking is more efficient in getting rid of the unused parts of the library.*

Comment: my this.service.getCity returns an Observable<any>. pipe -> error Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Comment: Could you post the method `getCity`?

Comment: getCity(city: string): Observable<any>  {
    return this.appService.get(`${this.url}/url?customer=${city}`);
  }

Comment: and `this.appService.get`...?  The error message you reported should appear just if the returning value of your `getCity` wasn't an `Observable`.

Comment: In my rxjs there is no pipe for the observable <any> return.

When I call this.appService.getCity ('city'). Pipe comes the error Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable <any>'

Comment: What version of `rxjs` are you using? pipeable operators have been around for a while...

Comment: "rxjs": "5.1.0",

Comment: That explains a lot... in version 5.1.0 there wasn't any `pipe` method. I'll change my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I posted a response on how I solved the problem I was facing

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by turning my canActivate method into an asynchronous method and calling getCity () with await.

```
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    let active = this.appService.isAuthenticated();

    await this.service.getCity('city');

    if (!active) {
      this.appService.redirectUrl = state.url;
      window.location.href = result.entity;
    }else {
      this.userInteractor.setCity(result.entity);
    }

    return active;
  }
```

@julianobrasil Thanks for the help, but it worked for me, then tell me if you agree with the solution. But once thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's ok!